# Can a 'test' user delete a MapR table? What are the permission needs to be granted to test user to delete a MapR table?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have created a new MapRDB table with the below privilege.

```
        "adminaccessperm":"u:root | u:mapr | u:test",
       "deletefamilyperm":"u:root | u:mapr | u:test",
      "defaultappendperm":"u:root | u:mapr | u:test",
        "defaultreadperm":"u:root | u:mapr | u:test",
       "defaultwriteperm":"u:root | u:mapr | u:test",
```

I am trying to delete the table as a test user. I am not able to delete the table. 
I am getting the below error. 
ERROR: User test(user id 503)  does not have access to /EDMEVENT/events_1

Answer (score 0):

You have to have full control permissions in order to delete.  You can modify cluster permissions using the acl set and acl edit commands, or using the MapR Control System.  Detailed steps can be found [Cluster and Volume Permissions](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Setting+User+Permissions)